# You don't have permission to access /owncloud/ on this server

Tags: apache-httpd

I installed owncloud and applied SSL on it, Later i create a virtual host for https

```
> <VirtualHost *:80>
>     ServerName owncloud
>     Redirect permanent / https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/ </VirtualHost>
> 
> NameVirtualHost *:443 <VirtualHost *:443>
>     SSLEngine on
>     SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/owncloud.crt
>     SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/private/owncloud.key
>     <Directory /var/www/html>
>     AllowOverride All
>     </Directory>
>     DocumentRoot /var/www/html/owncloud
>     ServerName owncloud
>     ErrorLog logs/owncloud-error_log
>     CustomLog logs/owncloud-access_log common
> 
>         <IfModule mod_headers.c>
>           Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=15768000; includeSubDomains"
>         </IfModule>
> 
> </VirtualHost>
```

And then restarted the HTTPD and accessed from browser and it was working fine. Then i restarted the OS , when it cameback online i again tried to access but this time i got this error

**Forbidden
You don't have permission to access /owncloud/ on this server.**

Permission for /var/www/html/
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 22 Nov  8 16:53 /var/www/html/

Permission for /var/www/html/owncloud
drwxr-xr-x 12 apache apache 4096 Nov 15 14:03 /var/www/html/owncloud/

Inside Owncloud directory

```
-rw-r--r--  1 apache apache 1.8K Sep 15 10:42 status.php
-rw-r--r--  1 apache apache 5.4K Sep 15 10:42 remote.php
-rw-r--r--  1 apache apache 3.2K Sep 15 10:42 public.php
-rw-r--r--  1 apache apache 3.9K Sep 15 10:42 index.php
-rw-r--r--  1 apache apache  179 Sep 15 10:42 index.html
-rw-r--r--  1 apache apache  31K Sep 15 10:42 db_structure.xml
-rw-r--r--  1 apache apache 4.9K Sep 15 10:42 cron.php
-rw-r--r--  1 apache apache 4.3K Sep 15 10:42 console.php
drwxr-xr-x 12 apache apache  225 Sep 15 10:43 settings
drwxr-xr-x  4 apache apache   39 Sep 15 10:43 resources
drwxr-xr-x  2 apache apache   23 Sep 15 10:43 ocs-provider
drwxr-xr-x  2 apache apache   73 Sep 15 10:43 ocs
-rwxr-xr-x  1 apache apache  283 Sep 15 10:43 occ
drwxr-xr-x  6 apache apache  101 Sep 15 10:43 lib
drwxr-xr-x  3 apache apache   32 Sep 15 10:43 l10n
-rw-r--r--  1 apache apache  34K Sep 15 10:43 COPYING
-rw-r--r--  1 apache apache  25K Sep 15 10:43 CHANGELOG.md
-rw-r--r--  1 apache apache 8.7K Sep 15 10:43 AUTHORS
drwxr-xr-x  6 apache apache  130 Sep 15 10:43 updater
drwxrwxrwx 25 apache apache 4.0K Sep 15 10:46 apps
-rw-r--r--  1 apache apache  271 Sep 15 10:47 version.php
lrwxrwxrwx  1 apache apache    5 Nov  8 17:28 data -> /data
drwxrwxrwx  2 apache apache   49 Nov 12 12:01 config
drwxr-xr-x 17 apache apache 4.0K Nov 13 09:36 core
```

> **SELinux is Disabled**

What i'm missing ?

Comment: This may have something to do with the difference between `Redirect` and `Rewrite` ... your `owncloud` configuration may be generating `http` links while the client is sent to `https` links...  You could probably check this by simply `mv index.php index_old.php` and `touch index.html` in your `/var/www/html/` directory... and see if you get the same error... if so, try `rewrite` instead and of course `mv index_old.php index.php` to set things back in order.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check:
https://doc.owncloud.org/server/10.0/admin_manual/installation/installation_wizard.html#post-installation-steps

There is a script that restores proper permissions after owncloud installation

Additionally, did you check apache2 error logs for more information?

Comment: I run the script and script ran successfully and i suppose if there ever was perm problem it should have fixed it, but still receiving same access denied message. in owncloud-error.log file im receiving this message "[Wed Nov 15 14:28:08.336169 2017] [ssl:warn] [pid 3437] AH01909: RSA certificate configured for owncloud:443 does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Wed Nov 15 14:28:08.436442 2017] [ssl:warn] [pid 3437] AH01909: RSA certificate configured for owncloud:443 does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
"